# Flask start-up command on azure for 'manage.py runserver'

Tags: python, azure, flask

I am unable to run the `python manage.py runserver` command from Azure. My manage.py code is

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_migrate import upgrade as upgrade_database
from glogic import app, db, prepare_app

prepare_app(environment='ms')
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

Where glogic is the package for the bulk of my python files. The prepare app method is called from the __init__.py file which is as follows:

```
from glogic.config import config_env_files
from flask import Flask

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# initialises app and db
db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)


# prepares the app and db environment based on config files
def prepare_app(environment='ms', p_db=db):
    app.config.from_object(config_env_files[environment])
    p_db.init_app(app)
    # load views by importing them
    from . import views
    return app
```

Running and hosting locally it all works but I have been unable to find the correct startup command or what to put in a startup.sh file in order to run the server on Azure.

When running locally, I can start it using the command `gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 manage:app` but this isn't working on Azure

Comment: Not sure if this will help with your specific issue, but this doesn't appear to me to setup the app the way you think it is. `app = Flask(__name__)` should be inside your `prepare_app` function and you shouldn't be importing `app` from `glogic` rather your should have `app = prepare_app(...)` in your `manage.py` file.

Comment: I tried this but its breaking more than its fixing